# Renaming all XML tag names in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with the prefix like this one:

```
<h:table>
 <h:tr>
 <h:td>Apples</h:td>
 <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
 </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
 <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
 <f:width>80</f:width>
 <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>
```

I want to rename the prefix moving the colon in favour of the dash, so:

```
<h-table>
 <h-tr>
 <h-td>Apples</h:td>
 <h-td>Bananas</h:td>
 </h-tr>
</h-table>

<f-table>
 <f-name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
 <f-width>80</f:width>
 <f-length>120</f:length>
</f-table>
```

Using the DOM parser I know that is possible to get elements by name, but in my case I need to take them all applying the renaming since the pattern  is always the same.

Now I have to write this function countless times, because one is just for one tag:

```
  NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h:table");
   for (Node eachNode: nodes) {
  document.renameNode(eachNode, null, "h-table");
  }
```

Is it possible to use a more general approach?

Comment: I'm not sure that is a good idea since `f:xxx` would mean that `f` is the namespace the tag `xxx` is defined in adn XML parsers probably rely on the colon-separator. Why do you need to change the colon to a dash?

Comment: I'm import xml in Neo4j using APOC, which completely ignores the namespaces with comma. So I need to change it by dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse and rename DOM elements recursively like this:

```
private static void renameElement(Document document, Element element) {
    document.renameNode(element, null, element.getNodeName().replace(':', '-'));
    NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node child = children.item(i);
        if (child instanceof Element) {
            renameElement(document, (Element) child);
        }

    }
}
```

Start recursion from the root element:

```
renameElement(document, document.getDocumentElement());
```

However, you should consider if you really want to break [XML namespace-well-formed conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#Conformance). Okay, it is  still conformant but you lose element namespace binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can always fall back to pain old text processing, you know. Just search and replace regex pattern.
search for

```
<([^:]*):(.*)>
```

and replace with `<$1-$2>` for starting tags.

If you have to do this in java, there is [java.util.regex package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html%20java.util.regex%20package).
But [sed rocks](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for such tasks.

Comment: messing with xml as text is almost always a bad idea

Comment: @jtahlborn Almost always. Perhaps not so in this case, assuming the OP only needs to do this once, and that we can reasonably be sure that the pattern does not appear inside some xml element. Pragmatism.

Comment: how do you process the xml as text without destroying the character encoding?  (note that xml is a binary format, not a text format)